# How to configure WAMP and Wordpress for regular site maintenance

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I am currently using WAMP to host a website on my local PC. I have two questions with regards to configuration:

1) Whenever I want to add something to my website, I am required to edit wp-config.php to point to the directory of localhost instead of my live site

```
/* Making edits with localhost
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/example');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/example');

/* Public site directory
/*define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com');*/
/*define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');*/
```

Is there an easier way to automate this? I can't imagine every person who uses WAMP with wordpress has to go through this process, am I missing something?

2) Whenever I have a virtual host for localhost, people who view my website are redirected to my localhost instead of the website. My config for http-vhosts.conf virtual hosts is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
 <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, I need to comment out the block every time my site goes live, then it works fine. However, whenever I want to make changes to my website, I have to uncomment the virtual host again. Similar to my first issue, is there an easier way to switch between site maintenance and online mode? Thanks in advance for any comments/suggestions.

Comment: WAMP is used locally and you should have a separate public installation for your *live* public site. WAMP is not meant for external access.

Comment: @Mulli, thanks for the feedback. I had thought that because WAMP has an online mode, it would work fine for public access because it sets the permissions for this purpose. Would you recommend some other distribution for hosting live sites?

Comment: `Would you recommend some other distribution for hosting live sites` - If I hosted my own sites, I would get a Linux server for it, but you could run them in a VM and that way you have all the benefits of linux.  Its much easier to secure etc...

Comment: I suggest that WAMP will be used locally only. It does not have the protection that you have on public installations. I am not hosting provider. Personally I am using SiteGround and happy with it. Specifically their support is truely 24/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMP is used locally and you should have a separate public installation for your live public site. WAMP is not meant for external access.

Local installation is not protected against attacks, nor heavy traffic. One should use some hosting service.

Once installations are separated, the above issue is resolved.

Comment: `One should use some hosting service` In most cases yes, but if you know what you are doing it can be fine...  At my Job we use both.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Totally agree! : "if you know what you are doing..." :-)

Comment: Yep, and even though I mostly know what I am doing we have an outside security expert go over everything and attack our stuff etc... he even tried phishing me one time and he left a flash drive by my car too.... ha ha ... :)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ... as in this case sometime the solutions for a dillema (or a problem) is to prevent its causes... :-)